# Attempted import error: 'swr' does not contain a default export (imported as 'useSWR'). - nextjs 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, next.js13, swr

I make project using nextjs 13.4.7 and already install swr in 3 PC but I got the same error:
Attempted import error: 'swr' does not contain a default export (imported as 'useSWR').
error TypeError: (0 , swr__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default) is not a function

my swr version is "swr": "^2.2.0"

I use swr like this:

```
import useSWR from 'swr';

function Todos() {

  // Define the fetcher function to fetch data from the API
  const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

  // Use SWR to fetch data from the API
  const { data, error } = useSWR('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/', fetcher);

  if (error) return <div>Failed to load todos</div>;
  if (!data) return <div>Loading todos...</div>;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Todos</h1>
      {data.map((todo) => (
        <div key={todo.id}>
          <h3>{todo.title}</h3>
          <p>{todo.completed ? 'Completed' : 'Not completed'}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Todos;
```

I hope someone can help me to fix it or report this as a bug from swr

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://github.com/vercel/swr/discussions/1867#discussioncomment-2219438

Answer (score 11):

I think you forget to type "use client" at the top of code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Try using 'use client' at the top of the page. I am also getting a similar error when trying to use the hook.

```
(0, swr__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.default) is not a function
```

I found that I forget to use 'use client'. I put 'use client' at the top then the error was resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Use "use client". It will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers.